# How to upload a bitmap with Fast Android Networking

Tags: android, kotlin, networking, bitmap

I'm trying to upload a image to a server as taken from camera with FAN. I've tried to convert into PNG and JPEG and encoded to image but adding multipart file it always shows me errors
Here's a fragent of my code while trying.

After taken the photo:

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
        bitmap = data!!.extras!!["data"] as Bitmap?
        encodeBitmap(bitmap)
    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
}
```

The function to encode bitmap

```
private fun encodeBitmap(bitmap: Bitmap?){
    val byteArrayOutputStream = ByteArrayOutputStream()
    bitmap!!.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream)
    val byteofimages = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray()
    encodedimage = Base64.encodeToString(byteofimages, Base64.DEFAULT)
    confirmarEntrega()
}
```

And the atempt to upload with FAN

```
private fun confirmarEntrega(){
        val uploadURL ="http://192.168.1.229/sistema.com/API/upload.php"
        val requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this)
        val txtNombre = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.txtClientName)
        val txtDireccion= findViewById<TextView>(R.id.txtDireccion)
        val txtProducto = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.txtProducto)
        val txtTelefono = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.txtTelefono)
        val scannerTextview = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.scannerTextView)
        val btnConfirmar = findViewById<Button>(R.id.btnConfirmar)
        progressDialog!!.setMessage("Espere un segundo")
        progressDialog!!.show()

        AndroidNetworking.upload(uploadURL)
            .addMultipartFile("image", encodedimage) //Here's where im lost
            .setPriority(Priority.HIGH)
            .build()
            .setUploadProgressListener(object : UploadProgressListener{
                override fun onProgress(bytesUploaded: Long, totalBytes: Long) {

                }
            })
            .getAsJSONObject(object : JSONObjectRequestListener{
                override fun onResponse(response: JSONObject?) {

                }

                override fun onError(anError: ANError?) {

                }
            })
}
```

Comment: `trying to upload a image to a server as taken from camera ` That is only a thumbnail of an image.

Comment: `tried to convert into PNG and JPEG and encoded to image` To jpg i see. And then encode the jpg base64.